# moveit build error- move_group_interface.h file not found

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS indigo,I had installed moveit from user binary.When i try to do a `catkin_make` I get the following error in moveit packages:-

```
home/<user_name>/catkin_ws/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/pr2_tutorials/pick_place/src/pick_place_tutorial.cpp

fatal_error: moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h : No such file or directory
#include moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h
compilation terminated!
```

I have made no changes to the moveit package.
move_group_interface.h seems to be included in every example code, I dont see how it can be missing.

As a result in the custom package that i have created I am using move_group instead of move_group_interface.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257250/moveit-build-error--move_group_interface.h-file-not-found/) by [Anirudh_s](https://answers.ros.org/users/29491/anirudh_s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noAimInLife](https://answers.ros.org/users/32360/noaiminlife/) on 2017-10-24**:
Why does it provide same clone link for both indigo-devel and kinetic-devel branch?. Downloading as zip worked though.

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-11-17**:
Because you clone **a git repository**, not a branch. You have to checkout the correct branch yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [moveit_tutorials](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials) repository has a separate branch `indigo-devel` that works on indigo.
You tried to compile the `kinetic-devel` branch that incorporates changes for MoveIt 0.9.x which is released in ROS kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5